# django-south: chicken+egg with initial data

Tags: python, django, django-south

I have a model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass
```

I want to add a type attribute to it. There are a fixed number of types. The existing ones should all have the default type. So I add the type:

```
class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And the types to an initial data fixture:

```
- model: app.Type
  pk: 1
  fields:
    name: "default"
- model: app.Type
  pk: 2
  fields:
    name: "special"
```

And modify `Foo`:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, default=1)
```

The `schemamigration` works fine. However, the `migrate` fails, since the `app.Type`s are not in the database yet, thus the default of 1 doesn't exist.

How do I solve this issue in a clean, elegant fashion? I could first put in the `Type`, migrate that, and then modify `Foo`, and migrate that, but it seems like that would only work on the local site (since when I migrate on a different site it'll do everything at once anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write an extra datamigration specifically for your initial data in the fixture. Check out South's docs on the subject http://south.aeracode.org/docs/fixtures.html#initial-data Hope that helps you out.

Comment: This worked. I just did a `schemamigration` as usual, then modified the migrate file, adding a `from django.core.management import call_command` on top and a `call_command("loaddata", "app/fixtures/init_X.yaml")` in the `forwards` function.